# Can you get unlimited Hooded Cleanroom suits in Fallout 4? (console)

Tags: fallout-4

I really want to equip a few of my settlers with the Hooded cleanroom suit, and whilst I know you can find one in the reactor room inside the Institute, I want to know if this suit will ever respawn anywhere or can be found anywhere else? thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanroom_suit)

```
They have a chance of spawning in Institute dressers.
```

So you may want to search the whole institute and farm these dressers.
Also it says on the internet that locked containers reset after 2-3 days (in-game time) so may be able to farm it.

*edit : posted before title update from OP*

Or, if you're on PC :

```
 player.additem 115aeb
```

Comment: When adding an item via console like that, you can also specify a number after the item ID. Using "player.additem 115aeb 300" will give you 300 of the suits instead of just one.